# CSS: Why do on hover animations stop when hovering ceases?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

Take the below CSS

```
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: transform .7s ease-out;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: scaleX(5);
  transition: all 5s;
}
```

This is triggered on hover, but when the mouse leaves the button the div returns to its original state.

Why is this?

Comment: because you no more hover on the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These CSS styles specified by your :hover selector apply ONLY when the mouse is currently hovering over the element. As soon as you un-hover, those css styles are deactivated

Basically, your CSS while your mouse is hovering will look like this:

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
transform: scaleX(5);
```

And your CSS while your mouse is NOT hovering will look like this:

```
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
```

while your transition styles help you smoothly transition between those two states

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense,

Answer (score 1):

You can consider a big delay on mouseout to keep the hover state:

```css
.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition-delay: 5000s;
  background:blue;
}

.button:hover {
  transform: scaleX(5);
  transition: transform .7s ease-out 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="button"></div>
```